# Turning a list that is already in dictionary format into a dictionary

Tags: python

I currently have a list

```
["Sun:70.00", "Zebra:80.00", "Blue:80.00", "Edwards:50.00"]
```

and I'm trying to turn it into a dictionary so it looks like this

```
{"Sun":70.00, "Zebra":80.00, "Blue":80.00, "Edwards":50.00}
```

but I cant figure out how to do it.

I tried using this code

```
dct = {listx[i]:listx[i+1] for i in range(len(listx))}
```

but it combines element 0 and element 1 of the list giving me a dicitonary with only to elements.

Comment: Have you tried breaking down the task, writing some pseudocode, etc. ?

Answer (score 2):

You can split the strings on the `':'` them and pass the tuples to the dictionary constructor. It works well as a simple generator expression passed into `dict()`:

```
l =  ["Sun:70.00", "Zebra:80.00", "Blue:80.00", "Edwards:50.00"] 

d = dict(s.split(':') for s in l)
# {'Sun': '70.00', 'Zebra': '80.00', 'Blue': '80.00', 'Edwards': '50.00'}
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use a dictionary comprehension:

```
l = ["Sun:70.00", "Zebra:80.00", "Blue:80.00", "Edwards:50.00"]

d = {k: v for s in l for k, v in [s.split(':')]}
# {'Sun': '70.00', 'Zebra': '80.00', 'Blue': '80.00', 'Edwards': '50.00'}
```

Comment: This has the advantage of being able to easily wrap the `v` in   a `float` if they don't want a string.